# Water Valve Functionality

Tags: fluid-mechanics, hydraulics, compressible-flow

Before to present my question, I have to say that I'm not a hydraulic expert.

I'm working on a water valve design and I found this model which work with a diaphragm and a spring. I want to consider all the variables acting in this mechanism in order to understand how it works.

This is how I think it works:

The water flow pushes the diaphragm to let the water flow pass through the valve, the dynamic pressure in the pipe is about 14 PSI. When the water tank starts to fill, buoyancy force acts against the float closing a little hole which acts like a water leak.

[image]

The water inside the diaphragm chamber generates a force that pushes the diaphragm up, sealing the water intake and cutting the water flow through the water tank.

[image]

When the water valve cut the water flow the static pressure in the pipe reach 40 PSI.

According to this, I have some questions:

1. What is the function of the spring?
2. The sealing force generates by the diaphragm is higher than the force according to the 40 PSI of static pressure, or they are equal?
3. The pressure inside the diaphragm chamber rises when the water leak is sealed?